# Scrapy TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, screen-scraping, scrapy

I am building a scraper using scrapy and I am getting the following error message and I cannot figure out why. I have looked at the scrapy documentation but I am not sure if there's something missing. I am trying to accomplish downloading the images from the site with the descriptions. I would like the descriptions to download into CSV and the images to download into a folder titled IMG.

Spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from NSIscrape.items import NsiscrapeItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline


class NsiscrapeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Nsiscrape"
    allowed_domain = ["yachtauctions.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.yachtauctions.com/inventory/"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//tr')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = NsiscrapeItem()
        item['location'] = site.select('td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['stock_number'] = site.select('td[3]/a/text()').extract()
        item['year'] = site.select('td[4]/text()').extract()
        item['manufacturer'] = site.select('td[5]/text()').extract()
        item['model'] = site.select('td[6]/text()').extract()
        item['length'] = site.select('td[7]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = site.select('td[8]/text()').extract()
        item['status'] = site.select('td[10]/img/@src').extract()
        item['url'] = site.select('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
        item['images'] = site.select('td/a[3]/img/@data-original').extract()
        item['image_urls'] = item['images']
        yield Request(item['url'][0],
        meta={'item':item},
        callback=self.product_detail_page)

def product_detail_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    #add all images url in the item['image_urls']
    yield item
```

This is the error I am getting when running the scraper

```
raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type
(url).__name__)
exceptions.TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:
```